# Open save as window and populate file name and file path from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open the save as window and populate the file name and file path from a cell

Here's the code I have which does populate the file name and opens the save as window in the file path but when I click save the file never shows up in the location where it was suppose to save.

```
Sub Save()

'Adds formula to show file path
ActiveSheet.Range("I26") = "=LEFT(CELL(""filename"",RC),FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC),1)-1)"

'Adds formula to show file name
ActiveSheet.Range("J26") = "=MID(CELL(""filename""),FIND(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1,(FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-FIND(""["",CELL(""Filename""))-8))"

ActiveSheet.Calculate 'Calculate sheet

'this will remove the formula from the cell making it text only
ActiveSheet.Range("I26") = ActiveSheet.Range("I26")
ActiveSheet.Range("J26") = ActiveSheet.Range("J26")


Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("I26").Value
FileName = ActiveSheet.Range("J26").Value


Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
    .InitialFileName = FilePath & FileName & ".xlsm"
    .Title = "Save your File"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    .Show
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I think it's because you have the `FilePath` in the file name.  Try `.InitialFileName = FileName & ".xlsm"`.

Answer (score 4):

The file dialog doesn't actually save the file - it just prompts the user for a filename or allows the user to change a default filename.  You have to get the selected filename back and save it independently something like this:

```
Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
  .InitialFileName = FileName & ".xlsm"
  .Title = "Save your File"
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
  End If
End With
```