# Macro to open Save As window and automatically populate file name and type

Tags: vba, excel

In order to help speed up the process of saving audit sheets there is a naming convention and that has been taken care of in a reference sheet within the workbook that has a cell `Defined Name` of `savefile_name`.

However the audit sheets are saved on a variety of computers in the field and are eventually migrated by each user into the archive once they return to the office. Therefore I would like my macro to open the `Save As` dialog, populate the name and select the `.xlsm` or `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook) format without fail.

My current code, [inspired by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865866/open-save-as-window-and-populate-file-name-and-file-path-from-cell), will happily open the `Save As` dialog, and populate the name, but it will not select the `.xlsm` format; it always has the last format selected as when the the `Save As` dialog was last opened. How to I stop this from happening?

My VBA code:

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Range("savefile_name").Value

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
  .InitialFileName = FileName & ".xlsm"
  .Title = "Save your File"
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  End If
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.FilterIndex = 2` inside the `with` statement.

Also, depending on the version of Excel you're working with, you may not need to add the `& ".xlsm"` to the end of the `.InitialFileName`. If you want more detail on how to find other extensions/make it more variable in your code; you could check out the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18259961/9259306)

---

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Range("savefile_name").Value

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
  .InitialFileName = FileName
  .Title = "Save your File"
  .FilterIndex = 2
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you that it was indeed what was missing. Thank you for the resource as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, I have the same problem to save in .xlsm and it's work on Excel 2013 :

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Range("savefile_name").Value

Dim fname As Variant
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Marcro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
InitialFileName:=FileName, _
Title:="Save your File")
If fname = False Then Exit Sub  'Exit if user hit Cancel
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fname, FileFormat:=52
```

Comment: This also works indeed however, even though in this case we do want it to be a `.xslm`, this method it actually disables all other save options of the `Save As` dialog. Even though its favourable it is limiting in case one day a version needs to be saved in another format. I will keep this code for that day. Thank you!